# Allow multiple people to work with single readonly excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a single read only excel file on a share that I would like multiple people to load into excel.  The file is read-only from the file system point of view to prevent them from changing the shared copy.  It is NOT read-only from an excel point of view.

Then they will make a couple of simple changes to a couple of fields and hit the print button.

They do not need to save their changes.

Right now they get an error when they try to do this:
"XXXX.xlsx is locked for editing."

Obviously I could make a copy of this file on each persons computer, but I would like the control of having it be readonly on a share.

I do not want nor need live updates so the other answers that apply to live updates do not apply.

Comment: Which version of Excel?

Comment: Do you know what "read only" means?

Comment: I suggest making a shortcut to open the file with Excel's read-only option set: `excel /r "C:\Users\ExampleUser\Documents\MyFile.xlsx"`. Multiple users can open the file read-only, make any local changes they want to, and then print the file.

Comment: You've addressed the closure issue, but you also seem to have answered your own question.  "Obviously I could make a copy of this file on each persons computer, but I would like the control of having it be readonly on a share."  Why not do exactly that?

Comment: All I did was follow a scurrying white rabbit, and now I’m talking to a smoking caterpillar and an invisible (but useful) cat.  How did this question ever get closed as a dupe of a question about concurrent write access when it was clearly about read-only access from the very beginning?  And @fixer1234, what do you mean by “Why not do exactly that?”  You’re throwing the OP’s question back into his face.  He’s asking *how* to do that,  and nobody has answered that (although [davidmneedham’s comment](https://superuser.com/q/1260941/150988#comment1855264_1260941) might be a tolerable workaround).

Comment: @Scott We are going to test @ davidmneedham solution in a couple of minutes.  That looks promising.

Comment: I think the root cause of some confusion that when I wrote read-only I am thinking file system, and the excel focused people are thinking excel feature.

Comment: @Scott, maybe I'm missing something.  The file on the share is and remains read-only.  You make a working copy on each computer.  Each user does what they need on their own copy and the original remains read only.  The OP said that was obvious, implying that doing it is not a problem.  It wasn't clear to me what, then, is the specific problem the OP is unable to solve, or what about that solution is unsatisfactory.

Comment: @fix1234 I desire to have it on the share so when I update it I only need to update it in one place.  If I distribute it to each computer, then I need to go to each computer to update it.

Comment: @davidmneedham I could not find a place to put excel in the shortcut to the file so I am creating a bat script that runs the command you mentioned.  The challenge I am facing is to run excel regardless of where it is installed on the machines.  I made this question to try to find a solution to that: https://superuser.com/questions/1261020

Comment: @MichaelPotter, you can't have it both ways.  If you want the original to be unchanged and read-only, the users can only have a copy and their changes will not be reflected in the original.  You also can't update their copies because you don't know what changes they've made to their own copies.  If you need a collaboration system, you may need something like Sharepoint.

Comment: @fixer1234  Read the question more carefully. They don't need to collaborate.

Comment: @davidmneedham - post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @MichaelPotter, having a master copy of a file that people can access, read, and print, but not change, is one thing.  You can have a shared file and people don't necessarily need their own copy.  If they download it and don't need to modify it, they don't need to save and maintain the copy.  They can discard it and download the current version if they need it again.  If users need a copy that they can modify, you can't update that from a master file.  You seem to describe a requirement for a solution to accomplish both, but they are mutually exclusive, at least with the software you mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the technique used here:
[bat script to start excel without hardcoded path and with command line options](https://superuser.com/questions/1261020)

Which is to create a batch script that looked like this (on shared drive):

```
START excel.exe /r "S:\The\Path\To\File.xlsx"
EXIT
```

And put a shortcut to that batch file on each user's desktop.

Both the bat file and the .xlsx file are readonly on a share (shared file system).

The .xlsx file is NOT readonly from an excel point of view because the users have to tweak a few cells before they print.  They only print and do not need to save their changes back to the disk.

credit to @davidmneedham for this answer.  I invite him to post an answer to this question and I will accept it so he gets the points.